# Monitor Usage and Switch Off

Tags: networking, server

Good day,

I am currently looking at renting a VPS server for our Gaming group to use as a TeamSpeak server. We would like to keep it local, but are limited to resources and funds.

I have found a solution that is within our budget that comes with Ubuntu installed, but has some limitations on the monthly allowed Bandwidth. Unfortunately the company doesn't stop the service once you have reached your monthly allowed Bandwidth and you are then charged with over usage at a premium rate.

I need to know if it is possible to track the monthly Bandwidth usage with Ubuntu and if it reaches a certain threshold to switch the VM off?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Monitoring network bandwidth tool(vnstat):

**install vnstat:**

```
apt-get install vnstat
```

**Monitoring command:**

`vnstat -m`  monthly bandwidth

```
root@test:~# vnstat -m

 eth0  /  monthly

       month        rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
    ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
      Feb '16    106.13 MiB |   95.41 MiB |  201.54 MiB |    1.70 kbit/s
    ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
    estimated       273 MiB |     245 MiB |     518 MiB |
```

`vnstat -d` daily bandwidth

`vnstat -h` hourly bandwidth

> Q.I need to know if it is possible to track the monthly Bandwidth usage
>   with Ubuntu and if it reaches a certain threshold to switch the VM
>   off?

you need to manually monitor the bandwidth if montly bandwidth goes above your hosting limit you can manully shutdown the vm or you can use ufw firewall to block traffic.(script can be made for shutting down vm)

**ufw firewall:**

```
apt-get install ufw

sudo ufw default deny incoming 

sudo ufw default deny outgoing
```

**Teamspeak bandwidth usage:**

if you are using good quility Codec audio(32KHz) each user will upload approx. 8KB/s of data.

considering 20 players 20*8= 160 KB/s(around 1GB in one hours).

considering 20 players playing 12 hours/day =12*1= 12GB/day

per month bandwidth usage = 30 * 12 = 360GB

**Note:** all players are not speaking at the same time.(if yes, bandwidth may increase)

considering 360GB/month is average bandwidth. Mostly all hosting provider provide around 500GB/month.

**counter strike 1.6 server with voice enable:**

I had cs 1.6 server which was voice_enabled and had 28-32 concurrent players. it was using approx 4-5GB/day.

**Source :**

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/11/vnstat-network-traffic-monitor/

http://humdi.net/vnstat/man/vnstat.html

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-an-ubuntu-and-debian-cloud-server

http://forum.teamspeak.com/threads/76111-How-much-Bandwidth-does-TS3-take